# Euler 004 - Excel. Why is this array not finding the largest palidrome?

Tags: arrays, excel, max

```
=MAX(B2:AHQ901*--AND(LEFT(B2:AHQ901,1)=RIGHT(B2:AHQ901,1),MID(B2:AHQ901,2,1)=MID(B2:AHQ901,5,1),MID(B2:AHQ901,3,1)=MID(B2:AHQ901,4,1)))
```

Attempting Euler challenge 004 in Excel 2013.
I have set up a simple spreadsheet that sums all 3 digit numbers.
The above array *should* find the maximum number in this spreadsheet that is a palidrome, but returns #value.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Not shown in the above formula, but I am entering it as an array with Cntrl+ Shift + Enter

Comment: If that formula returns `#VALUE!` as an array formula then somewhere in `B2:AHQ901` is a non numeric value.

Comment: For me it works but it returns zero. I don't get why you go up to AHQ901; I think it should be AHP900.

Comment: Hi Axel, Thanks for the reply. Turns out I wasnt understanding array logic with the AND operator. Fixed now to =MAX(IF(IF(LEN(B2:AHQ901)=6,((LEFT(B2:AHQ901,1)=RIGHT(B2:AHQ901,1))*(MID(B2:AHQ901,2,1)=MID(B2:AHQ901,5,1))*(MID(B2:AHQ901,3,1)=MID(B2:AHQ901,4,1))),0),B2:AHQ901,0))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that formula returns `#VALUE!` as an array formula then somewhere in `B2:AHQ901` is a non numeric value.

But there is also an issue with the using of  `AND` in array context. The `AND` will be evaluated first with the whole array. It will **not** be evaluated for each array element. So the whole `AND` will be false if only **one** comparison is false in the whole array.

It should be:

```
{=MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(B2:AHQ901),B2:AHQ901)*
(LEFT(B2:AHQ901,1)=RIGHT(B2:AHQ901,1))*
(MID(B2:AHQ901,2,1)=MID(B2:AHQ901,5,1))*
(MID(B2:AHQ901,3,1)=MID(B2:AHQ901,4,1)))}
```